# How to backup SQL Server Agent jobs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, backup, sql-server-agent

How can I backup and restore SQL Server 2005 Agent job schedules?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the msdb database is where all the jobs live, it is one of the system databases

Comment: Here's a relevant MSDB article on considerations of restoring MSDB: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190749(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can also script all the jobs out as a sql file and store them in svn or other source control if you'd like to track changes.