# How to backup SQL Server Agent jobs?

Tags: sql-server-2005, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to backup SQL Server Agent jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094040/how-to-backup-sql-server-agent-jobs)

Hi,I want to backup my sql server 2005 Agent jobs to another server,
How can I backup and restore SQL Server 2005 Agent job schedules?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094040/how-to-backup-sql-server-agent-jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Agent jobs are stored in the `msdb` database.  This database is invisible by default, to show it set "Show system databases" to true in the connection registration properties.

This question is probably a better match for www.serverfault.com.